# select mutual numbers in database table

Tags: mysql

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

please friends this is a table for users who are fiends so i want to select the mutual friends for user 1 and user 2. and the mutual friends are all the users marked in circle, i grouped each user with a specific color: here is my coding:

```
    SELECT * FROM friends AS f5
INNER JOIN 
((SELECT one FROM friends WHERE two =  '1') AS f1,
(SELECT two FROM friends WHERE one =  '1') AS f2,
(SELECT one FROM friends WHERE two =  '2') AS m1, 
(SELECT two FROM friends WHERE one =  '2') AS m2)
ON (f1.one  = m1.one AND f2.two = m2.two )
```

Comment: You deleted the image reference. Please include the image again.

Comment: How does `f5` relate to `f1`, `f2`, `m1`, or `m2`? That relationship seems to be missing from your SQL. Perhaps the missing picture will clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

The `JOIN` condition you provide in your query does not put any constraint on `f5`, so it will certainly return too many records, and in many cases duplicate records as well.

Secondly there is also no link between the pair `f1`, `m1` on the one hand, and the pair `f2`, `m2` on the other. So again, this will lead to a Cartesian product and return far too many records.

There are several ways to write an SQL statement to get mutual friends for two given persons, based on your table structure.

Here is one:

```
SELECT      fr1.id
FROM        (
            SELECT CASE WHEN one = 'Helene' THEN two ELSE one END id
            FROM   friends
            WHERE  'Helene' in (one, two)
            ) AS fr1
INNER JOIN  (
            SELECT CASE WHEN one = 'Eric' THEN two ELSE one END id
            FROM   friends 
            WHERE  'Eric' in (one, two)
            ) AS fr2
        ON  fr2.id = fr1.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30eba/2).

Just make sure to insert the name of the first person twice in the first sub-query, and the name of the second person twice in the second sub-query. I have taken the names "Helene" and "Eric" in the above example.